# Bind 'art_ID' to image when renaming

Tags: php, file, rename

How do I rename all images within a folder and bind `art_ID` from my database to the new names and add some prefix in case there is more than one image?

This is what i tried:

```
$directory = 'tmp_img/';
foreach (glob($directory."*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $file = realpath($filename);
    $result = substr($filename, 0, 19); //takes first 19 characters to replace 
//files in the folder have a random 9 digit number (478-391-601.jpg)

    rename($file, str_replace($result,"tmp_img/". $item['art_ID'] ,$file));
}
```

It does change the name but somehow `$item['art_ID']` seems to be an empty string resulting in `tmp_img/.jpg` instead of  `tmp_img/264330.jpg`

Any idea on how to solve this problem?